# Will iphone copy to iCloud pictures migrated from Android?

Tags: iphone, icloud

I migrated an Android phone from to iPhone, using the Move to iOS app.
I wonder if my pictures copied from Android will be synced to iCloud.

It synced new pictured made on iphone but still did not copied migrated ones.